# UNITY c#:is it possible to change True and False button to 4 different button choices and still using "public bool"?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, boolean, generic-collections

I made a quiz but true and false are the only buttons,

Got them from a tutorial which is brackeys

how do I make them to 4 buttons with 4 different choices.

and assign them to button objects in unity

here are my codes for true and false(GameManager.cs)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public Question[] questions;
private static List<Question> unansweredQuestions;

private Question currentQuestion;

[SerializeField]
private Text factText;

void Start()
{
    if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
    {
        unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
    }
    SetCurrentQuestion();
    }
    void SetCurrentQuestion()
    {
    int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
    currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[randomQuestionIndex];

    factText.text = currentQuestion.fact;

    unansweredQuestions.RemoveAt(randomQuestionIndex);
    }
   public void UserSelectTrue()
   {
          if (currentQuestion.isTrue)
   {
          Debug.Log("CORRECT");
   } else
   {
          Debug.Log("WRONG");
   }

   public void UserSelectFalse()
   {
          if (!currentQuestion.isTrue)
   {
          Debug.Log("CORRECT");
   } else
   {
          Debug.Log("WRONG");
   }
    }
```

Question.cs

```
 [System.Serializable]


 public class Question {

 public string fact;


 public bool isTrue;


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a way for each question to have more than one answer but act similar to a bool then you are probably looking for something like this:

```
enum Response { yes, no, maybe, dontknow }
public Response answerToQ1;
```

Add that to your code, then look in the inspector, it works as a dropdown menu.

To compare its current state:

```
if (answerToQ1 == Response.yes)
    //correct
else 
    //incorrect
```

or

```
switch (answerToQ1) {
    case Response.yes:
        //correct
        break;
    case Response.no:
        //incorrect
        break;
}
```